# asp.net mvc5 + iis express 10, maxAllowedContentLength and maxRequestLength don't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I need to do uploading files on site and have following web.config (huge values are done only with test purpose now):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="9999999" />
  </system.web>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebSite" />
      <add namespace="React.Web.Mvc" /></namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="400000000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that I still can't upload several files. It looks like when I try to upload files with total size in 4Mb I get error about exceeding max request limit. Does anybody have ideas how to find out what is a reason of this?
I've already spent a lot of time without good results and a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a max request length in httpRunTime in the main Web.Config file, not the one in views.

e.g. 16MB

```
  <system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="16777216"/>

<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</httpModules>
```